# Show stuff everywhere except single post?

Tags: functions, single

I was trying to add stuff on my header everywhere except single post using 
(!(is_single) but it doesnt work.

```
<?php if(!(is_single) ){?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.png"/>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [is_single](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) is WordPress function so you should add parentheses after it as displayed in the following correct code.

```
<?php if ( ! is_single() ){ ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image.png"/>
<?php } ?>
```